# (C#) win10 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word でメモリーリーク発生

Tags: c#

vs1015,win7でワード(.doc)からテキスト抽出するのに以下のソースでおこなっていましたがwin10にしたところメモリーリークが発生するようになってしまいました。どう対処したら良いのかご教示の程よろしくお願いします。

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = null;
try
{
    word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    object path = @"c:\1\1.doc";
    object readOnly = true;
    docs = word.Documents.Open(
        ref path,
        ref miss,
        ref miss,
        ref miss,
        ref miss,
        ref miss,
        ref miss,
        ref miss,
        ref miss,
        ref miss,
        ref miss,
        ref miss,
        ref miss,
        ref miss,
        ref miss,
        ref miss);

       //テキスト抽出処理

}
catch
{
}
finally
{
    object oMis = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    object oTru = true;
    object oFal = false;
    if (docs != null)
    {
        docs.Close(ref oFal, ref oMis, ref oMis);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(docs);
        docs = null;
    }

    object saveOption =  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
    object originalFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOriginalFormat.wdOriginalDocumentFormat;
    object routeDocument = false;
            ((_Application)word).Quit(ref saveOption, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument);

    if (word != null)
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(word);
        word = null;
    }
    GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: 何の指標値をもってメモリリークと判断したのでしょうか？ その指標値の改善をもってメモリリーク解消と判断するのでしょうから、そこが提示されないことには回答のしようがありません。また、その指標値は「//テキスト抽出処理」では上昇しないものなのでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。　未熟な質問で申し訳ありません。//テキスト抽出処理　には何も書かないで　上記のソースを1回実行するとタスクマネージャでのメモリー使用率が２％づつ増えていき最後は９８％まで行きパソコンが固まってしまい再起動しております。このメモリー使用率が増えないようにしたいという事で投稿させていただきました。どうぞご指摘よろしくお願いします。

Comment: メモリー使用率は集計結果ですので、その内訳を確認し、リークしているプロセスを提示してください。このプログラム自身ですか？ Word本体ですか？ Wordのゾンビが大量に残ってたりしませんか？

Answer (score 3):

リーク個所が提示されないので当てずっぽうですが、

```
((_Application)word).Quit(ref saveOption, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument);
```

.NETの中でも、COM Interopにおいて**型キャスト**はCOMにおける`QueryInterface()`に相当します。`word`オブジェクトの新たなコピーを作成し、作成されたコピーに対して`Quit()`を呼び出すことにもなりかねません。不要なキャストは避けるべきです。

挙げられたコードはVisual Studio 2008以前の書き方ですので、Visual Studio 2010以降の書式で整理すると

```
var word = new Application();
var docs = word.Documents.Open(@"c:\1\1.doc");

//テキスト抽出処理

docs.Close(false);
word.Quit(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges, WdOriginalFormat.wdOriginalDocumentFormat, false);
```

で済みますが、これでも同様の問題が発生するのでしょうか？

Comment: コードの提示ありがとうございます。
早速　提示コードで試してみたところ結果は同じでした。
そこでプログラム以外が原因かといろいろ試したところ、原因がわかりました。
現在、セキュリティソフトとして　「ウィルスセキュリティ」(win10対応office2013)を使用しているのですがこのソフトを起動したままで手動でワード・エクセルを起動するたびにメモリーが減っていくのが確認できました。（職場の同僚のパソコンも同様でした。たぶん日本中で同じ現象が起きているのでは？）
ちなみにこのソフトを無効にすると正常にメモリーを開放してくれます。

とりあえずメーカーにバグ報告をしてアップデートを待つことにします。
今回はお付き合いありがとうございました。